# bibtex not compiling natbib journal style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle

I am trying to use the following [template](http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/file/0005/109382/elsarticle-template-harv.tex) for a journal article and within the example they use natbib for the references and they also provide the following referencing style: [model2-names.bst](http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/file/0015/109410/model2-names.bst). Here follows the MWE I am plaing with, with no luck at all.

```
%% This is file `elsarticle-template-2-harv.tex',
%%
%% Copyright 2009 Elsevier Ltd
%%
%% This file is part of the 'Elsarticle Bundle'.
%% ---------------------------------------------
%%
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%%
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'Elsarticle Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%%
%% Template article for Elsevier's document class `elsarticle'
%% with harvard style bibliographic references
%%
%% $Id: elsarticle-template-2-harv.tex 155 2009-10-08 05:35:05Z rishi $
%% $URL: http://lenova.river-valley.com/svn/elsbst/trunk/elsarticle-template-2-harv.tex $
%%
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}


\journal{Medical Image Analysis}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {First Article Title Apha}
}
@misc{A02,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Second Article Title  Beta }
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Some Title}

%% use optional labels to link authors explicitly to addresses:
\author[label1,label2]{First Author}
\author[label1]{Second Author}
\author[label2]{Third Author}
\address[label1]{first University Name}
\address[label2]{Second Univeristy Name}


\begin{abstract}
Some workds about this work

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword \sep keyword
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

% \linenumbers

%% main text
\section{First Section}
bla bla bla bla \cite{A01}

\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}

%%
%% End of file `elsarticle-template-2-harv.tex'.
```

If I use their style the Bibtex crashes.

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013) The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template-2-harv.aux I couldn't open style file model2-names.bst ---line 3 of file elsarticle-template-2-harv.aux : \bibstyle{model2-names : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file elsarticle-template-2-harv.aux (There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

When switching the comments to disable model2-names style and activate plain style it goes through the bibtex but then while compiling the latex it complains as it could not find the year tag in the references.

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

Comment: If you put `model2-names.bst` in the same directory as `elsarticle-template-2-harv.tex` and recompile, what happens?

Comment: well now is when I feel shamed and stupid. I downloaded the `.bst` convinced that I place it on the right place (aka the current directory) but it was not there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing file.